# Custom moderncv theme

Tags: moderncv

I've tried to make a custom moderncv theme, as I didn't want my CV to look like all the others Latex-made CVs.

But I'm facing a (minor) problem: pdflatex doesn't recognize it, and I get a `! LaTeX Error: File 'moderncvstylecustom.sty' not found.`, even though this file exists and is in the same folder as the other moderncv themes (which is `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/` in my case). I have to supply it the absolute path to this file every time, and it gets annoying after a few compilations.

Has anyone an idea on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance,
viod

Comment: did you texhash?

Comment: No, I hadn't, but it solved my problem! Thanks a lot!